# C++ Eclipse Mac Hello World

Tags: c++, eclipse, xcode, gcc

I am using Lion, Mac OX X 10.7.5 and Eclipse Juno to try and learn to program using C++. I created a new project using the hello world template. When I tried running the hello world program I got 3 errors:

> Program "make" not found in PATH
>   Program "gcc" not found in PATH
>   Program "g++" not found in PATH

I have Xcode downloaded also. I selected the toolchain MACOSX GCC.

Comment: A similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473259/os-x-eclipse-c-launch-failed-binary-not-found) that can help, also includes a [check list for OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13757230/833336) answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install gcc in Mac OS X Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998384/how-to-install-gcc-in-mac-os-x-lion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you downloaded Xcode, you also need to download the command line tools package from within Xcode which will install the necessary `make` program and `clang` compiler.

To download it go to  Xcode >> Preferences >> 'Downloads Tab' and install `Command line tools`.